# Error when displaying a link preview: Attention Required! | Cloudflare

Tags: preview, cloudflare

I am building a website where a user can post a comment with a link and a link preview is generated. However for some websites instead of getting a preview I see `Attention Required! | Cloudflare`. After doing some research I found this [topic in Cloudflare support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203366080-Why-do-I-see-a-captcha-or-challenge-page-trying-to-visit-a-site-protected-by-CloudFlare-as-a-site-visitor), where they dive into this issue, here is a quote incase url changes in the future:

> A site visitor to a website that Cloudflare is protecting can see a
>   captcha for the following reasons:
>
> 1. The IP address you are on has shown problematic activity online recently in one of our data sources. If you would like to look your IP
>      up, then please look your IP up at Project Honeypot. If the IP address
>      shows data for malicious activity, you can see why there. You can also
>      attempt to whitelist your IP directly on that page by connecting from
>      that IP.
> 2. The site owner decided to block the country you are visiting from.
> 3. Your actions are triggering a Web Application Firewall rule that the website owner has turned on.
>
> What to do:
>
> 1. You can still enter the site by passing the captcha. You can also request to the site owner that the whitelist your IP address. You must
>      have cookies and JavaScript enabled in your browser settings to pass
>      the captcha. If you are running any anti-virus or firewall programs on
>      your computer, then you may also need to check to make sure that they
>      aren't blocking access to the captcha image.
> 2. If your IP is showing that you are distributing malware or spam, your computer may have an infection and we would recommend running an
>      anti-virus scan.

The website is hosted with WPEngine in United States.

1. I checked the server IP(as the previews are generated on the server) and it was not blacklisted on Project Honeypot.
2. Since the websites which return `Attention Required! | Cloudflare` are as large as https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com or https://medium.com/ it is difficult to believe that they have blocked their sites from USA.
3. I have reached out to those websites in order to whitelist our domain name and IP address in their systems and currently awaiting for a response.

I want to note that I also requested a scan from our web hosting(WPEngine) and they said they did not find any suspicious activity on our site.

I would like to ask if there is something else I can do to prevent this from happening and avoid it in the future?